# Authentication failure is shown while configuring git repository to Bamboo

Tags: git, bamboo

Authentication failure is shown while configuring git repository to Bamboo

Error message-An error occurred while testing connection. Please verify your repository configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Add Git repo server host SSH key  to the list of Trusted keys.

**Reason**

The trusted key is used to secure communication. It prevents bamboo from connecting to unauthorized services via SSH.That is how it implements security.

[More deatils](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/managing-trusted-keys-800714520.html)

[Reference 1](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/Bamboo-and-Git-Link-Repository-Authentication-Failed/qaq-p/196013)